# How to pass part of computer traffic through Cisco Anyconnect?

Tags: virtualbox, proxy, virtualization, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop. I've also have VirtualBox installed, and a virtual Windows 7 machine set up. The network configuration of my virtual Windows is as follows:

1. Bridged Adapter for Adapter 1;
2. Host-only Adapter for Adapter 2.

Now, in my Ubuuntu I open up my browser (Firefox) and configure it to forward traffic through address `192.168.56.101:808` (my virtual Windows Host-Only Adapter address).

In my virtual Windows I have Cisco Anyconnect VPN, CCProxy, and Psiphon. Now

1. When Anyconnect is fully closed, and Psiphon and CCProxy up and running, and CCProxy is set to cascade traffic through address `127.0.0.1:9090` (Psiphon's local HTTP/HTTPS port), then my Ubuntu browser is able to browse all filtered websites.
2. When Psiphon is fully closed, Anyconnect is running and connected, CCProxy up and running, and also CCProxy cascading is disabled, then my Ubuntu browser has no access to any website (I get `The connection has timed out` error). But the browsers in my virtual Windows can access any website without any problem.

I need my Ubuntu traffic to pass through CCProxy and Anyconnect (For some reason I do not want to install Anyconnect or OpenVPN on my Ubuntu itself). How can I achieve the configuration I need?

Comment: Could you share all the private IP address configurations in VM and host? How did you configure it to forward traffic? Do host and VM ping each other through host-only IPs?

Comment: @Biswapriyo How can I obtain private IP address configurations? Is there a specific command to use?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Isn't it a security risk to share my private IP address configs?

Comment: Only Private one, starting with 192.168... or 172... Or 10... Those are not routable. No one can't connect private network from outer world. If you don't want to share it, it's ok.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'd prefer not to share them, since there is bunch of info in the command output, and I'm really not sure what the consequences of sharing them would be.